# Testing Kernel modules across multiple kernels

Tags: testing, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, integration-testing, kernel-module

How do you test a kernel module across a bunch of kernels for a given distro release?

Given a kernel module on which to perform integration tests, we have a suite and EC2 instances linked up to Artifactory as their yum/apt provider.  Ansible scripts run yum/rpm or apt/dpkg to install the new kernel before modifying grub and rebooting the system.

So, this approach works with a few issues:

- time to change kernel is 2-4m making runs acrosss 10s or 100s of kernels either lengthy or expensive in AW$.
- rpm / dpkg won't automatically install required dependencies and yum / apt will but some maintainer management practices cause kernels to go missing from metadata after deprecation making these tools blind to what we cache in Artifactory

We could use a tool like packer to make AMIs for each kernel and then instantiate them for testing.  This might be a cleaner solution.

How do y'all who test kernel modules across scores of kernel versions approach this problem?

Comment: Did you try https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @tk421 when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a way ?